# Kindle paperwhite and sharing quotes with goodreads for side-loaded books

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, amazon

I want to post quotes from my kindle paperwhite to goodreads but share button always disabled.

I tuned progress posting and finding books in goodreads using this [question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/3644/trouble-hooking-up-goodreads-with-sideloaded-ebook-on-kindle-paperwhite) and I found information that quotes sharing available only for USA, Canada and Australia but I am from other country.

I try to find difference between amazon book from which I can post quotes and my sideloaded book from which I can't post quotes and I didn't find it.

Are there anybody who found the way to share quotes for sideloaded books?

Comment: Good reads is owned by Amazon. For some reason some things in good reads only work,with books bought from the kindle store. Eg ratings when you end the book on the kindle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good, common question that seems to have an answer here: [Trouble hooking up Goodreads with sideloaded ebook on Kindle Paperwhite](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/6187/10427)

> I have found the best way to get it 100 percent working is this:
>
> - If your book is not already in AZW3 format then convert it. (Has to be AZW3 and not just AZW.)
> - Secondly, highlight the book and edit metadata.
> - Once you are at that screen delete any other format that you have shown in the top right side leaving only AZW3.
> - Delete the tags by hitting the recycle icon next to the tags box and hit download metadata.
> - Once you have done that make sure the only tags you have are ISBN, Google, goodreads and amazon. You may not have all 4 but make sure
>     that you do not have any mobi-asin tags.
> - Save and download the quality check plug in for calibre.
> - Highlight the book and click on the quality check icon at the top, look for 'fix' on the drop down menu and click 'fix asin for kindle
>     fire'. Don't worry it will also work for paperwhite etc.
> - Delete any copy you already have on the device and resend.
> - For completeness I also go to the top of calibre and click device and update the cached metadata on device.
> - Eject device and you should be good to go! Full integration with goodreads as if you had purchased through Kindle store.

Alternatively, try using the [Quality Check](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=125428) tool:

> Get the [Quality
>   Check](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=125428)
>   plugin for Calibre and then use it's "Fix -> Fix ASIN for Kindle Fire"
>   feature. It expects that you have the Amazon ID in the book's metadata
>   somewhere, which should be there if you download the metadata using
>   Calibre. This inserts the ASIN and allows goodreads integration to
>   work. I tested it myself.
>
> One annoying thing is that it seems that if the Kindle notices that
>   there's a `mobi-asin` field (which the above introduces in order to
>   fix Goodreads integration), then it seems to download and use the
>   cover art that Amazon has for that book, instead of the one you set in
>   Calibre. I'm not sure if there's a way to circumvent that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but my best guess is that Share quote feature requires that a book loaded on your Kindle be identifiable on Goodreads. This is trivial for Kindle books with their ASIN ids, but not so easy with sideloaded content. If I were in this situation, I would try finding out if I could manually assign ASIN id to a sideloaded book using Calibre or some such other tool (assuming the book exists on Goodreads database in the first place).

HTH

Comment: Amazon ASIN is needed to share reading progress too. I set it via calibre in sideloaded book, but I can't share quotes